# Not showing typos and errors I make

Tags: delphi, editor

When I write code (and make mistakes in e.g. typing, or type mismatches)* the editor normally indicates immediately the problem. But now I have managed to switch this function off somehow. I need to **compile/build** the code to get the errors listed in the bottom screen, as usual.

*I sometimes make use of this by deliberately putting a useless letter in a long code to quickly get back to that point later...By clicking on the spotted error message.*

This probably a stupid issue no doubt, but I really would appreciate some help. Thanks.
Fred

In the **Tools/Options** the **Formatter Profiles and Status** tab the **Enable Formatter** is enabled.
Restarting Radstudio does not help.

Applies to all the code now.

Comment: Note that when debugging error insight is turned off.

Comment: The formatter has nothing to do with the question you're asking. It's for formatting code, as in properly indenting begin..end pairs and code blocks. It has nothing to do with the compiler whatsoever. In what way does the editor normally immediately indicate the problem? Are you talking about the red wavy lines in thej code editor and  *Errors* section of the Structure View? And what specific version  of Delphi?

Comment: Hi ken, indeed, the red wavy lines don't appear anymore, In addition, I used to get an error message (upper left: a box indicating something is wrong in that code line). Very basic, but also very helpful. Can't get that functionality back.

Answer (score 0):

The option you need is (in 10.3 Rio, may be slightly different in older versions):

*Tools → Options → User Interface → Editor Options → Code Insight →* [x] *Error Insight*

That should be set. You may want to play around with the other options on that tab as well.

Comment: Thanks, In Berlin 10.1 I cannot find the User Interface as indicated, however the Editor Options -> Code Insight -> Error Insight I found, It was already checked. I am afraid this was not the cause of my problem.

Comment: @Fred: in Rio, some of the options were re-categorized and the layout of the dialog is not entirely the same as in previous versions like Tokyo or Berlin. I don't have anything else but Rio here, sorry.

Comment: Hi Rudy, I understand. I found the _Error Insight_ you wanted me to change, no problem. But I still have this poor editing functionality to work with. No clue how to get it back to 'normal'.